# What are the geometric, harmonic, and quadratic averages of a function?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, average, means

In [Mean of a function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_of_a_function), they describe the arithmetic mean of a function and at the bottom of the article they said:

> There is also a harmonic average of functions and a quadratic average (or root mean square) of functions.

My question is what is the form of these averages?

Comment: Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square and see if you can generalize the concepts to functions.

Comment: For example the harmonic average of a function is presumably the reciprocal of the mean of the reciprocal of the function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically, if $(X,\mathscr{B},\mu)$ is a probability space, and $\phi$ is nice bijective function from $(a, b)$ to another interval $(c, d)$, then the $\phi$-mean, defined for measurable  functions $f: X\rightarrow (c,d)$ for which $\phi\circ f$ is integrable  is defined as $$\phi^{-1}\Big(\int\phi\circ f\,d\mu\Big)$$
The most common examples are

1. $\phi(x)=x$ (arirthmetic mean)
2. $\phi(x)=\log(x)$, $x>0$, (geometric mean)
3. $\phi(x)=\frac{1}{x}$, $x>0$ (harmonic mean)
4. and $\phi(x)=x^p$, $x\geq 0$ (the $p$-mean).

In many applications of the means described in 1-4, one considers  $|f|$, which is nonnegative, and defined
$$|f|_\phi:=\phi^{-1}\Big(\phi(|f|)\,d\mu\Big)$$
When $\phi(x)=x^p$, the space $L_p(\mu):=\{f:|f|_\phi<\infty\}$ is a (complex) linear space and $|\;|_p$ defines a (pseudo)-norm that is complete. As Prof. GEdgar mentioned in his comment below, $\phi(x)=x^2$ corresponds to the **quadratic mean** (or **quadratic norm**).

Comment: "Quadratic average" is $\phi(x) = x^2$, also called "root mean square": $$\left(\int |f|^2 d\mu\right)^{1/2}$$  Stated with absolute value in it so that the definition can be used for cases where $f$ has complex values.